# Build failure trying to add new jars to maven project on the server

Tags: java, apache-commons-email

I have a Jsf 1.2 maven application. I try to send automatic-report emails to users regarding the application daily usage. I add the required Jar files in my local project workspace and it works fine. I can send the email without any problem. However, when deploying the project war to server machine, the new jar files are not seen by the tomcat web-server. Although I add all the dependencies in pom.xml. What would the problem If the project works in local machine and does not work in remote server?

Comment: can you explode your war file and see location where jar file exist

Comment: Actually, all the project jars reside inside a repository folder in local and remote server. I'm sitting the jars artifactId in pom.xml. The application works that way. I'm a new starter indeed.

Comment: When I make any changes in the project, I upload it to the remote server and deploy it. It is working; the project jar file reads all the jars that reside in the same folder with project jar. Though when I add a new jar in my local computer, the project reads it and use all the functions inside the new jar. However, when I build the project with the new jar and put it to the remote server , the server gives error that the new jar classes does not exist. What should I do? I really appreciate your consideration.